# I am looking to set and an array in java while setting a sub method in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I have seen  other array codes but here is what I got. I am trying to set the courseID in the CollegeCollege course in the array. I need to set the array in the student.java

```
public class CollegeCourse {

private static String courseID;
private static int creditHours;
private static char grade;

public static void setCourseID(String course){
    courseID = course;
}
public static String getCourseID(){
    return courseID;
}
public static void setCreditHours(int CH){
    creditHours = CH;
}
public static int getCreditHours(){
    return creditHours;
}
public static void setGrade(char g){
    grade = g;
}
public static char getGrade(){
    return grade;
}


public class Student {

private static int IDnumber;
private static CollegeCourse[] course = new CollegeCourse[5];

public static void setIDnumber(int x){
    IDnumber = x;
}
public static int getIDnumber(){
    return IDnumber;
}
public static String getCourse(int x){
    return course[x].getCourseID();
}
public static void setCourse(CollegeCourse newCourse, int ID){
    CollegeCourse.setCourseID = newCourse[ID];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could seem like you are trying to code that the student takes course with id 5. Maybe your classes should have constructors taking arguments based on what ID the course has.

and I don't know what you need the fields to be static for, bt feel free to have them static if it is needed for some reason.

```
public class CollegeCourse {

private String courseID;
private int creditHours;
private char grade;

public CollegeCourse(String courseID) {
    this.courseID = courseID;
}

...

public class Student {

...
private static CollegeCourse[] course = new CollegeCourse("5");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better design would be this:

```
public class CollegeCourse {

    private final String courseId;

    private final int creditHours;

    public CollegeCourse(final String courseId, int creditHours) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
        this.creditHours = creditHours;
    }

    public String getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public int getCreditHours() {
        return creditHours;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) { return true; }
        if (!(o instanceof CollegeCourse)) { return false; }
        CollegeCourse cc = (CollegeCourse)o;
        return courseId.equals(cc.courseId) 
            && creditHours == cc.creditHours;                   
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       int result = 17;
       result = 31 * result + courseId.hashCode();
       result = 31 * result + creditHours;
       return result;
    }
};

public enum Grade { A, B, C, D, E };

public class Student {

    private final String id;

    private final Map<CollegeCourse, Grade> course2GradeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Student(final String id) {
        this.id = id;       
    }

    public Grade getGrade(final CollegeCourse course) {
        return couse2GradeMap.get(course);
    }

    public void addCollegeCourse(final CollegeCourse course, Grade grade) { 
        course2GradeMap.put(course, grade);
    }

    public Collection<CollegeCourse> getCollegeCourses() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(course2GradeMap.values());
    }
};
```

Use it in this way:

```
Student student = new Student("001");
student.addCollegeCourse(new CollegeCourse('alg', 100), Grade.A);
student.addCollegeCourse(new CollegeCourse('stat', 100), Grade.C);
```